# javaScript number.toString()

Tags: javascript

`+[...number.toString()]` the code ,I have problem;
`[...number.toString()]` can work.but
`number.toString()` will not work;

> VM5906:2 Uncaught TypeError: number.toString(...).reverse is not a function
>             at reverseInteger (:2:30)
>             at :1:1

```
const reverseInteger = function (number) {
   return +[...number.toString()].reverse().join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings do not have a `.reverse()` method. What your `reverseInteger()` function does is convert the number to a string, and then converts the string to array containing each character in the string

```js
function reverseInteger(number) {

    // convert the number to a string
    let text = number.toString(10);

    // convert the string to an array of characters
    let charArray = [...text];

    // reverse the array of characters
    let reversedCharArray = charArray.reverse();

    // put the characters back together into a single string
    let reversedText = reversedCharArray.join('');

    // convert the reversed text back into a number and return it
    return +reversedText;
}
```

Comment: Strings do not have a reverse. Number does have a toString: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString - no need for a concat

Comment: Operator precedence is my second question. Thank you for solving my question

Answer (score 2):

> `number.toString(...).reverse`

changes number to string and then calls reverse on string, will throw an error as there's no `reverse` method available for `string`

> `[...number.toString()].reverse`

works because after changing number to string you're `spreading` it into an `array` and then `reversing` it

Comment: I'd rather use *cursive* or **fat** to highlight words, `code` is meant for code....

Answer (score 0):

`String` have no `reverse` method, but they do have a `split` method you can use:

```
const reverseInteger = function (number) {
    return +number.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
}
```